# ASP.Net using DAL result doesn't get set to handler

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Okay I am trying to use DAL on my project but when I get results and add it to the data table once I return from pulling the value from DB.

ASPX Page:

```
UserDetails us = new UserDetails();

UserHandler Handler = newUserHandler();// Starts

Handler.GetUserDetails(Email); //  comes out 

Display.Text = us.Code; // null
```

UserHandler.CS

```
namespace LoginSystem Handler
{
    public class UserHandler
    {
        UserDBAccess UserDb = null;
        public AspUserHandler()
        {
            UserDb = new UserDBAccess();

        }

        // This fuction does not contain any business logic, it simply returns the 
        // list of employees, we can put some logic here if needed
        public User GetUserDetails(string email)
        {
            return UserDb.GetUserDetails(email);
        }
    }
}
```

UserDBAccess.CS

```
public class AspUserDBAccess
{

    public UserDetails GetUserDetails(string Email)
    {
        UserDetails AspUser  = null;
        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@PUserEmail", Email)

        };
        using (DataTable table = SqlDbHelper.ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand("GetUserDetails", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters))
        {
            if (table.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
                AspUser = new UserDetails();

                AspUser.Code = row["Code"].ToString();

            }

        }
        return AspUser;
    }



}
```

Sqlhelperclass.CS :

```
   internal static DataTable ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand(string 
                  CommandName, CommandType cmdType, SqlParameter[] param)
   {
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            cmd.CommandText = CommandName;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);


            try
            {
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(table); // just "{}" but doesnt say null

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    return table; // {} nothing in table
}
```

//

So I again I see it get the value but it seems like it never sets it and goes back to the ASPX page. UserDetails has null

Comment: If you don't assign the return value of _Handler.GetUserDetails(Email);_ to your _UserDetails us_ variable in the main code you will never see what is the result of your efforts

Answer (score 1):

How about changing

```
UserDetails us = new UserDetails();
Handler.GetUserDetails(Email);
```

To

```
var us = Handler.GetUserDetails(Email);
```

This way you actually use the return value of your method instead of throwing it away and looking at a variable you assigned an empty `UserDetails` to.

By the way, this looks weird:

```
public User GetUserDetails(string email)
{
    return UserDb.GetUserDetails(email);
}
```

Since UserDb.GetUserDetails returns 'UserDetails', not 'User':

```
public UserDetails GetUserDetails(string Email)
```

Comment: I'm going to try it and yeah, this is code from work so I was changing it up to different names to not expose code lol felt like the right thing to do. But I knew I would leave a mistake once I started changing the code on this post.